# Event expected to raise but is not raised

Tags: .net, vb.net, events

I'm having problems trying to raise an event in this class

```
Private Sub Check()

    If Me.DaysLeft <= 0 Then
        RaiseEvent Expired(Me, New ExpiredEventArgs With {.DateExpired = TrialDateEnd})
        MsgBox("yes")
    Else
        RaiseEvent Active(Me, New ActiveEventArgs With {.DaysLeft = Me.DaysLeft})
        MsgBox("no")
    End If

End Sub
```

The msgbox is shown, but the event is not raised.

In my Form1 I have this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents _TrialExpiration As New TrialExpiration(4)

    Private Sub TrialExpiration_Active(sender As Object, e As TrialExpiration.ActiveEventArgs) _
    Handles _TrialExpiration.Active

        MsgBox(String.Format("You have {0} days remaining.", CStr(e.DaysLeft)))

    End Sub

    Private Sub TrialExpiration_Expired(sender As Object, e As TrialExpiration.ExpiredEventArgs) _
    Handles _TrialExpiration.Expired

        MsgBox(String.Format("Your copy of this software expired on {0}.", e.DateExpired.ToString))

    End Sub

End Class
```

And this is the TrialExpiration class:

```
#Region " TrialExpiration "

Public Class TrialExpiration

#Region " Variables "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The date that the expiration started.
    ''' </summary>
    Private TrialDateStart As New Date(Nothing)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The date that the expiration ends.
    ''' </summary>
    Private TrialDateEnd As New Date(Nothing)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Expiration days.
    ''' </summary>
    Private TrialDays As Integer = 0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Expiration days left.
    ''' </summary>
    Private DaysLeft As Integer = 0

#End Region

#Region " Events "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Event raised when trial date is active.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event Active As EventHandler(Of ActiveEventArgs)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Event raised when trial date has expired.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event Expired As EventHandler(Of ExpiredEventArgs)

    Public Class ActiveEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Expiration Days left.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property DaysLeft As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class ExpiredEventArgs : Inherits EventArgs
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Expiration Date.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Property DateExpired As Date
    End Class

#End Region

#Region " Constructor "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new Trial Expiration.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="TrialDays">
    ''' Amount of days to expire.
    ''' </param>
    Public Sub New(ByVal TrialDays As Integer)
        Me.TrialDays = TrialDays
        SetTrialDates()
        GetDaysLeft()
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Public Methods "

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Resets the Trial Expiration.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Reset()
        My.Settings.TrialDate = String.Empty
        My.Settings.Save()
        '  My.Settings.Reload()
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region " Private Methods "

    Private Sub SetTrialDates()

        ' If it's application first time run then set the initial date as Today.
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.TrialDate) Then
            My.Settings.TrialDate = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Today.ToString))
            My.Settings.Save()
            My.Settings.Reload()
        End If

        Try
            TrialDateStart = Date.Parse(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(My.Settings.TrialDate)))
        Catch ex As FormatException
            ' Exception thrown if the user has corrupted the base64 string from the settings file.
            ' Then truncates the initial date to force trial expiration.
            TrialDateStart = Date.Parse("0001/01/01")
        End Try

        TrialDateEnd = TrialDateStart.AddDays(Me.TrialDays)

    End Sub

    Private Sub GetDaysLeft()

        Me.DaysLeft = (DateTime.Now.Subtract(Today) - DateTime.Now.Subtract(TrialDateEnd)).Days

        If Me.DaysLeft <= 0 _
        OrElse Today < TrialDateStart Then
            ' "OrElse Today < TrialDateStart" explanation:
            ' If the user has manipulated the date in the OS.
            RaiseEvent Expired(Me, New ExpiredEventArgs With {.DateExpired = TrialDateEnd})
        Else
            RaiseEvent Active(Me, New ActiveEventArgs With {.DaysLeft = Me.DaysLeft})
        End If

    End Sub

#End Region

End Class

#End Region
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your code logic in the Trail class because it worked fine. Since `check` is private but uses ME, I assume it was supposed to be a Trial Method.  I replaced all the settings variables with hardcoded dates, but otherwise Check raised an event and the form caught it.  There are some conceptual flaws with the design, but the events work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the event handlers lately in the `Form1.Load`:

```
AddHandler _TrialExpiration.Active, AddressOf _TrialExpiration.Active

AddHandler _TrialExpiration.Expired, AddressOf _TrialExpiration.Expired
```

instead of `Handles ...` statements.

As a side note, I actually don't see any reason to use events in this case...

Comment: Thanks but don't worked even adding the handler manually. I don't know what is the strange reason but I always created the events in the same way and always worked, but not this time.

Comment: Ok, why in the first code box you call `RaiseEvent ... (Me ...` but in the last box you call `RaiseEvent ... (Nothing ...` ?

Comment: the object that I pass as "sender" does not matter in this case, but anyways in the first example is "me" and in the last is "nothing" because I was trying to solve the unknown error.

Comment: I've updated the class code, you can paste it into a new project to test it with the eventhandlers of the code above, really I can't understand why those events will not be raised. thanks anyways!

Comment: @Teejay The main reason to use an Event for a license expiry is to delay reporting the expiration so as to make cracking a bit harder. If the Expired MSg comes up right after a call to XXX, it becomes pretty easy to find the code that does the evaluation.  If the License Class delays sending the Status event a random number of milliseconds, it becomes just a little harder to find the core code that determines the status.  Actually ANY MsgBox telling the status makes it easier. Without a delay, an event (and certainly 2 when eventargs would do) has little utility here.

Comment: @Plutonix If I need to be honest I added the events just to reporting the values on the application start but not for any cracking question, anyways I always used 3rd party apps to obfuscate and to add profesional trial protection, this trial code is just an easy alternative made in five minutes. and well, since I don't know the reason that why the events does not raises I've changed the events to public properties and now is working fine. But I still like to know the reason that why events don't raises there.